# Invalid signature error from ethers when trying to verify a Smart Contract Wallet(account abstraction) signature

Tags: javascript, ethereum, smartcontracts, signature, ethers.js

I am working on a dapp that needs to verify users' signatures. When testing with Metamask, everything is okay.

When trying to verify a signature from Ambire wallet, I get "Error: invalid signature string" from ethers.utils.verifyMessage
For example, here's the signature I got from Ambire:
`0xf1b5f561c1914d513f4020edd397f729836e26eeae8f1b9e4070d134492aa38b0a84b9d7cefe06f180ade91595fd74c4e845c2b8c2d053fa57785fdf5ec5dca31c01`

When I try to verify it this happens

```
require('ethers').utils.verifyMessage('test', '0xf1b5f561c1914d513f4020edd397f729836e26eeae8f1b9e4070d134492aa38b0a84b9d7cefe06f180ade91595fd74c4e845c2b8c2d053fa57785fdf5ec5dca31c01')
Uncaught:
Error: invalid signature string (argument="signature", value="0xf1b5f561c1914d513f4020edd397f729836e26eeae8f1b9e4070d134492aa38b0a84b9d7cefe06f180ade91595fd74c4e845c2b8c2d053fa57785fdf5ec5dca31c01", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.6.1)
```

Any idea if this can be solved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to support smart wallets like Ambire, Gnosis Safe, Argent, and others, you need to [implement EIP 1271](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1271).

Ambire universal signature verification, supporting:

- Standard message verification (eth_sign)
- 712 Typed data verification (eth_signTypedData_v*)
- 1271 Smart contract on-chain verification (isValidSignature)
  An optional smart contract signature off-chain verification (eg if the smart wallet is counterfactual and not deployed yet)

Simple eth_sign verification using [@ambire/signature-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ambire/signature-validator)

```
const ethers = require('ethers')
const { verifyMessage } = require('@ambire/signature-validator')

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('https://polygon-rpc.com')

async function run() {
    // Replace `ethers.verifyMessage(message, signature) === signer` with this:
    const isValidSig = await verifyMessage({
        signer: '0xaC39b311DCEb2A4b2f5d8461c1cdaF756F4F7Ae9',
        message: 'My funds are SAFU with Ambire Wallet',
        signature: '0x9863d84f3119ac01d9e3bf9294e6c0c3572a07780fc7c49e8dc913806f4b1dbd4cc075462dc84422a9b981b2556f9c9197d76da7ba3603e53e9300869c574d821c',
        // this is needed so that smart contract signatures can be verified
        provider,
    })
    console.log('is the sig valid: ', isValidSig)
}
run().catch(e => console.error(e))
```